# Как заблокировать все кнопки при нажатии одной из них?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно блокировать кнопки после нажатия любой из них на 5 секунд. Как я могу это сделать? Именно на 5 вроде через `Thread.sleep(sleepTime)`, но у меня не получается в `onClick`'е отключать кнопки например так:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная мысль - ждать не в главном потоке:

```
public void onCLick() {
    someBtn.setEnabled(false);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { someBtn.setEnabled(true); } });

        }
    }).start();
}
```